# Retrieve Sharepoint site collection list using RESTful api in Office 365

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I need to retrieve the list of Sharepoint site collections using the REST API for Office 365. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

No REST endpoints exist at the farm level in SharePoint, so there is no REST endpoint for all the site collections in your farm/tenancy.

Please refer to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections